# The magnetic field between two intersecting cylinders

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetostatics

> Consider a cable of infinite length whose section has the form of two intersecting circles of same radius $a$. The first part is then a cylinder of constant volume current density $J$ along the positive $z$-axis while the second has the same volume current density $J$ but along the negative $z$-axis. At the intersection of these two cylinders there is an empty cavity. Find the magnetic field $B$ at any point $P$ of this cavity.

What I did is apply Ampere's law as follows:
For the first part, I considered it to be a complete cylinder:
$$2 \pi r B_1 = \mu _0 J \pi r^2$$
$$B_1= \frac{\mu _0 J r}{2}$$

Assuming $d$ is the distance between the axes of the cylinders, we get for the second cylinder:
$$2 \pi (d-r) B_2 = -\mu _0 J \pi (d-r)^2$$
$$B_2= -\frac{\mu _0 J (d-r)}{2}$$

By applying the right hand rule we notice that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are along the same line, in the same direction so we can add them: $$B=B_1 + B_2$$ $$B= \frac{\mu _0 J(2r- d)}{2}$$

I worked with two complete cylinders since I assumed that superimposing them would cancel $J$ out in the intersection since both $J$'s have the same value but are in opposite directions. I'm not sure whether or not this assumption is valid. Can anyone provide an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your assumption of $J$s cancelling out in the intersection is valid, your conclusion that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are along the same line only holds along the line joining the centers of the circles. More generally, that is not the case; we can get a more complete solution (which also correctly takes care of the directions) by using the vector quantities $\mathbf{J}$, $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{d}$ (with the latter two measured from a point on the axis of one cylinder).

In this case, we get (for points in the cavity):
$$\mathbf{B}_{1}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_0 \mathbf{J} \times \mathbf{r}}{2}$$
$$\mathbf{B}_{2}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_0 (-\mathbf{J}) \times (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{d})}{2}$$
The net field is simply given by their linear superposition:
$$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) = \mathbf{B}_1(\mathbf{r}) + \mathbf{B}_2(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_0 \mathbf{J} \times \mathbf{d}}{2}$$
An interesting thing to note here is that the magnetic field is uniform throughout the cavity.

Comment: Then if $J$ is along the positive $z$-axis, and $d$ along the positive $y$-axis, (having chosen a frame centered at the axis of the first cylinder) $B$ will always be parallel to the $x$-axis ?

Comment: Yes, $B$ will be parallel to the (negative) $x$-axis.